# How do we pass arrays from java to stored procedure in oracle

Tags: arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

How to pass an array of Strings from java to stored procedure ?

What is the IN parameter in the stored procedure to receive an array ?

What I am trying to do is, for all the values(Ids) present in the array, I fetch the rowfrom table X and insert it into table X_Audit

Comment: look at this post
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416815/pass-java-array-into-plsql/8417069#8417069][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416815/pass-java-array-into-plsql/8417069#8417069

Comment: See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:712625135727 for a working example with a table of int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just spend the last few days working out a lot of JDBC related stuff, and one of my challenges was working out the answer to this exact question. I wrote up my solution on my blog: http://betteratoracle.com/posts/26-passing-arrays-between-java-and-oracle-procedures

You need to create some collection types on the database, and make the input parameters of the procedure have a type of the collections you created.  See the article I posted above for full details and working code.